# Maven artifact - How to obtain all statistics (Not only download on Maven central)?

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

I created and deployed on Maven Central a Maven artifact. Is it possible to obtain information on each use? Whenever a user uses this archetype Maven I would like a request to be sent to one of my server with the **data entered by the user (groupId, artifactId, version, ...)**

Answer (score 7):

It depends on what you used to deploy your artifact to Maven Central repository. I deployed mine though [Nexus Repository manager](https://oss.sonatype.org). On that site, if you log in, you can go to the "Central Statistics" tab, and there you can see the number of downloads and number of IPs from which downloads where performed.

Comment: that's exactly what I do not ask (Not download statistic on Maven central). I want data entered by the user (groupId, artifactId, version, ...)

Comment: I know your nswer is quite old, but how do you get those download statistics ? It seems to require a "project" value to be entered, and the dropdown list is empty

Comment: I think a day or two per month drop box is empty and I think (just my guess) that it is when the data about your repo is collected. But most days when you log in the drop box is not empty at least for me.

Comment: And also, at least for me stats on the previous month can come very late in the next month. Like stats for April can come on May 19th. Sometimes earlier and sometimes later.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, mvnrepository.com does not provide download statistics details. But you will be able to its popularity and usage statistics. See the screen shot below. For example, commons-lang3, you can only it is used by how many artifacts.

[image]

[image]

You can also check this link for reference.
https://www.reddit.com/r/java/comments/3u9sf0/why_no_public_stats_on_maven/

Comment: that's exactly what I do not ask (Not download statistic on Maven central). I want data entered by the user (groupId, artifactId, version, ...)

Answer (score 0):

What you asked for seems impossible to obtain :

- there is [no executable code in an archetype](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html), so you cannot send yourself a request to one of your server,
- as far as I know Maven itself does not collect those kind of usage statistics (and if it did I dare to hope that it would be a public and known information).

So I think the best you can obtain is the number of downloads and the number of unique IPs for your archetype through Nexus Repository manager, as explained by Michael Gantman.